# Derby Java DB, new autoincrement

Tags: java, sql, database, derby, javadb

I created a database table in my java DB database today and when I used this line in my create statement:

```
BOOKID INT not null primary key GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
```

The line below was in the structure when I used the grab structure option.

```
BOOKID INTEGER default AUTOINCREMENT: start 1 increment 1 not null primary key
```

I thought that autoincrement wasn't allowed in javaDB.
Is this a new update to java DB? 
Do both statements do the same operation?

When I tried to run the 2nd sql statement, it won't allow it. Just wondering if this may cause problems further down the line. I'm using the database on netbeans.

Comment: What is the "grab structure option"? You can read about Derby's syntax for generated columns here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqlj37836.html#rrefsqlj37836

Comment: @bryan the grab structure allows u to recreate a table  using its sql for another database.